# Windows 2008 Server Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

I developped a script to extract scheduled tasks on Windows 2012 R2, and it worked super fine in powershell. But actually I have an issue because I have a 2008 server, which seems not have the Get-ScheduledTask cmdlet.

I was trying to extract some tasks (whose name is pretty long). I tried using

```
schtasks.exe /tn "Start*JOB*"
```

but without succeed as the cmd returns and error

```
ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My question is : can we use wildcard characters to find a task/job by some letters rather than the whole name ? Otherwise, is there any other solution to obtain the same result ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SCHTASKS /Query` and parse the return for your desired task.

```
SCHTASKS /Query | Where-Object { $_ -like 'Start*JOB*' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a ComObject instead you could work within PowerShell to manage the scheduled tasks.

```
$Scheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$Scheduler.Connect()
$RootFolder = $Scheduler.GetFolder('\')
$MyTask = $RootFolder.GetTasks(0) | ?{$_.Name -like "Start*JOB*"}
```

Then you could manipulate your task as desired (start/stop it via methods, change triggers, whatever you wanted to do). Or if nothing was returned you could make a new task via the `$Scheduler` object.

For that matter, you can supply a remote server name to the `.Connect()` method and manage the tasks on a remote computer that way, and not have to directly interact with the older 2008 server.

More info on the Task Scheduler API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could consider updating PowerShell by installing WMF 2.0 and 3.0.

Execute `get- scheduledtask` and pipe it into `Where-Object`. Read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx

Sorry, I misread that you don't have scheduled task cmdlets on your machine.